# Refreshing module with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have working ajax code that refresh module number 158 and its class .xac-container in every 5 minutes. This module is accordion and the code is refreshing it. I need more simplified code for other module with number 312 just to refresh its class .globalnews in every 5 minutes which is not accordion and don't have first and active states. How this can happen?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

window.setInterval(function(){
    update_all_msl_forms("https://mysite/", false, false, "livematch");
  }, 5*60*1000); // 5 minutes


  function reload_tabs() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'https://mysite/',
      type: "get",
      success :function(response){
        var html = jQuery(response).find('#Mod158').html();
        jQuery('#Mod158').html('');
        jQuery('#Mod158').html(html);
        jQuery('.xac-container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
        jQuery('.xac-trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container
      }
    });
  }

  window.setInterval(function(){
    reload_tabs();
  }, 300000);

  jQuery(document).on('click', '.xac-trigger', function(){
      if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
          jQuery('.xac-trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all "active" state and slide up the immediate next container
          jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add "active" state to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
      }
      else{
          jQuery('.xac-trigger').removeClass('active');
          jQuery(this).next().slideUp();
      }
      return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
  });
});
</script>
```

I am very bad with javascript and don't have idea

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.